# positioning elements left and right of a div with margin:auto

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a set width (in pixels) that is centered by `margin: auto;`. How can I position an element to the left or right of this div, with a width that is dynamically adjusting to however wide the margin of the center div is?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: more info...

basically, it's the following setup:

```
<div></div>
<div style="margin:auto; width: 950px">content goes here</div>
<div></div>
```

I want to have the same background image on the left and right of the center div, but a different one in the center div. So how do I align the left and right divs to the, well, left and right of the center div, with a width that covers the entire margin of the center div.

Comment: If an element is dynamically adjusting to however wide it's parent is then surely it doesn't need to be aligned left or right? - Because it's filling the entire parent?

Comment: can you show ur code as well ask question in detail and better is post a image also of your desired result.....

Comment: Can you please explain more? left or right div is inside the margin:auto div? post with your code..

Comment: thanks for your comments. i edited the question and added more info.

Comment: you want "content goes here" div always stay in center with width 950px, and left and right div need to fill remaining...Is that you need?

Comment: Your selected best answer with the different background alone, then why you mentioned left and right div in your question?

Comment: Please check my latest comment on that answer and see that I unchecked the answer. I can't think of any other way to solve this than to have three divs side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as well... I have made the widths smaller (to fit a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Neograph734/Vb4Hm/1/). If you you should edit both margin-left's.

```
<div style="margin:auto; width: 250px; background: red;">    
  <div id="left_sidebar" style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-left: -200px;">
    <div id="right_sidebar" style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-left: 450px;">

    </div>
  </div>

Content here

</div>
```

Update:
The content should be below the floating divs

Comment: well, the problem is that the sidebars should fill the entire margin, regardless of how wide the screen is. Then again, I could just set the values to unreasonably high numbers :) Which is probably still better than using JS for this.

Comment: ok I'm going with this one, without js and tables it's probably the best option. And I have spent way too much time on this issue to continue looking for answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is only the background you can do like this:

```
<div style="background: url('path/to/image.jpg'); background-size: cover; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
  <div style="margin:auto; width: 950px">content goes here</div>
</div>
```

It projects the background on the background div. Then on the inside div you can specify another background that will go over the background of the parent div.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Trouble is, the background image in the center is a png with transparency, as are the background images on the sides. If I use this solution, the two background images will overlap.

Comment: It can be done otherwise, but it would make things unnecessary complex I think. Could you remove a piece of the background div? Like add a white bar from top to bottom? or specify the background from the inner div as `background: url('path/to/image') #ffffff; `

Comment: yes! I feel stupid now that I haven't thought of this (the background color as a secondary to the image), thanks so much. Let me try it.

Comment: ah, it works perfectly but I can't use that either. I just noticed that I have content that goes underneath the background image...

Comment: Why would you do that.... :S Oke, we do it the difficult way. Let me write another answer

Comment: It's basically a header shadow, with an arrow downwards ( that has a shadow as well ) in the center div that overlaps content. Looks pretty :) If you have another idea I'd be thankful if you'd write it down.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1:***

Easily can solve this by `table`, just use like this

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
       <td background="your/image/url5">content...</td>
       <td width="950" background="your/image/url">content goes here...</td>
       <td background="your/image/url5">content...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you can use all three block for writing content , also with different content

***Solution 2:***

If you need with `div`, then you need to write little jQuery for this

**html :**

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center">content goes here...</div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

**css :**

```
<style>
.left{
    background:url(your/image);
    float:left;
}
.center{
    background:url(your/image);
    float:left;
    width:950px;
}
.right{
    background:url(your/image);
    float:left;
}
</style>
```

**jQuery :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var window_width = $(window).width(); // get window width
    var total_remain = $(window).width()-950; // (-) your center div width
    var apply_width = total_remain / 2; // get remaining and divide by 2
    $(".left").css("width","apply_width"); // appying the width to the right / left
    $(".right").css("width","apply_width"); // appying the width to the right / left
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. However, using tables or JS for a thing like this is something I want to avoid, purely for emotional reasons. That said, those are valid answers and would probably work.

Comment: If i can see your design, i can give perfect answer...this answer may be a assumption...