# Place <div>-Container on the right side of a margin:auto centered <div>

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to position a div on the right side of a other div which is centered via margin:auto. (Like a sidebar)

Simple HTML:

```css
#c1{
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
    width:300px;
    margin:auto;

}

#c2{
 background-color:#BBBBBB;
 width:100px;   
 }
```

```html
    <div id="c1">con1</div>
    <div id="c2">con2</div>
```

I have tried the solution from this question but it does not work in my fiddle. The second div is in the next line. Link:
[positioning elements left and right of a div with margin:auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509395/positioning-elements-left-and-right-of-a-div-with-marginauto)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positioning to create this effect:

```
#c1{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    width:300px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}

#c2{
    background-color:#BBBBBB;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-100px;
    top:0;
}
```

And then you need to rearrange the HTML to look like this:

```
<div id="c1">
    con1
    <div id="c2">con2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="c1">
    con1
    <div id="c2">con2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#c1 {
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    width:300px;
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
}

#c2 {
    background-color:#BBBBBB;
    width:100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uu6teknz/)

Answer (score 1):

Using `position` property and a little moderation in your *DOM* you can easily achieve this.

Here's the **Code**:

```css
  .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    #c1 {
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
        width:300px;
        margin:auto;
        height:100px;
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        top:0;
    }
    #c2 {
        background-color:#294596;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div id="c1">con1</div>
       <div id="c2">con2</div>
   </div>
```

It will do the trick for you.